# XSD Schema for the JSON Body

Tags: json, xml, xsd, tags, informatica

I would like to get the XSD schema for the below JSON Body.

```
[
    {"text": "Hello"},
    {"text": "How are you?"}
]
```

For instance, if I convert online the above JSON body to XML and then to XSD schema, it gives the below output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="row">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The intent is to use the XSD schema in Informatica Rest web consumer transformation.
With the above XSD schema, the JSON body is creating as below, which is not desired request body:

```
{"row": [
    {"text": "Hello"},
    {"text": "How are you?"}
]}
```

Is there anyway, I can skip the `row` tag?

Any help in this regard?

Comment: No such XSD can possibly represent the literal JSON `[ {"text": "..."}, {"text": "..."} ]`. All XML documents must have a root element, which must be named; this is why the converter just used a default name, 'row' to represent the JSON array `[]`. Also why is this even necessary? You have JSON, but you're inferring an XML schema from it, only to then use it to generate more JSON? Why can't you infer a JSON schema instead of an XSD?

Comment: JSON array which I showed here is for the reference. I have to generate an XSD schema to be further used in the Informatica transformation. 
Using the XSD schema, Informatica internally generate the JSON body based on the schema which we define. Once the JSON body is properly formed, it will be sent as POST method request to the Rest API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON and XML have different data models, which means that lossless round-tripping is generally impossible. If you want to achieve it, you will need to write custom code that understands your specific data. A good tool for this job is XSLT 3.0.